# LaTeX journal article not compiling

Tags: natbib, compiling, overleaf, journal-publishing, abbrvnat.bst

**Case:**
I've prepared an article for a journal using a template on Overleaf. It compiles 
fine on Overleaf, looks great, and is ready for submission.

I pulled off the zip file, followed their upload instructions to a 't', but the document will NOT compile on the journal submission website.

**Two possible 'clues':**

**1.** I noticed that two files not directly referenced in the actual `main.tex` file (see image).[image: screenshot of submission to journal] 
*Notice that the logo.png and the .bst files are not "grouped" in with the main.tex*

**2.** The journal seems to get this a lot and here is what it says in their FAQs.

*My LaTeX (.tex) main document successfully uploaded, but it appears in red at the file upload step along with the error message "Unable to Convert File.". How do I fix this?*

This issue most often occurs when there is an incompatibility or other issue with the .bib or .bst file. To resolve the error, delete the uploaded .bib or .bst file, incorporate the contents  (copy/paste)  of the .bbl file generated in the LaTeX run into the LaTeX (.tex) main document, and then comment out the reference in the LaTeX (.tex) main document to the separate .bib and/or .bst file.

**Appeal**

Unfortunately, this is essentially nonsense to me. I have no idea how I would 'cut/paste' an entire style file into the main.tex, nor do I know how I would get the main.tex to "refer" or "point" to itself and not the style or bst file.

Are journals notoriously bad for not compiling? Am I wasting my time? Is there something obvious going on here?

If useful, I can provide a tex processor log (which is entirely nonsense to me), but not a reproducible example. Like I said, it works just fine on Overleaf. If the zip file with everything in it would be of use, I can also provide.

Comment: Can you provide the log and zip file, and I will take a look :)

Comment: In your Overleaf project, if you click on "Submit" and then choose e.g. "arXiv", there will be an option to download a .zip with the .bbl included. Once you click the button, it should show a "Please wait" message and take a while. Then the button comes back, only this time it is a download link that will immediately download the zip archive. Inside the .zip there's a `.bbl` file. Copy the entire contents of that `.bbl` file, and paste it inside your `main.tex` where `\bibliographystyle{abbrevnatemph}` and `\bibliography{sample}` were; you can delete these two lines from your `main.tex`.

Comment: Regarding the .png file: you might need to check if the journal's submission site only accepts .eps images? Because it looks like the .eps file was grouped with the .tex.

Comment: Thank you @Ole Anders - the link to them is [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1XzFuAYZzmXrUhGs-i6xQ4XIHRfmFMgfI?usp=sharing) (I hope this is how you meant to share).

Comment: Allright, I will get back to you in a little while.

Comment: The log file you sent me, is that from Overleaf?

Comment: No @Ole Anders, the logfile is from the compiler on the academic submission website. I have a perfectly lovely document compiled on Overleaf (I've added it to the box), and when I try to upload to the journal it refuses to cooperate.

Comment: I think I've got the answer now, if not, contact me on Twitter, and we can take the discussion further there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** As it turns out, after an hour of troubleshooting. It is in fact Oxfords own issue. Their template is not even compiling upon upload. The OP will contact the publisher directly to solve this.

When you try to include the eps file:

`\includegraphics[trim={0 0 0 0},clip, width=\textwidth]{STRCPRcropped.eps}`

The log file indicates that their compiler fails when trying to convert the eps file to pdf, as is first shown on line 610 onwards:

`Package epstopdf Warning: Drivers other than 'pdftex.def' are not supported.`

thus failing with:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \epstopdfDeclareGraphicsRule
```

To solve this, you should convert your file to png and include it like this:

`\includegraphics[trim={0 0 0 0},clip, width=\textwidth]{STRCPRcropped.png}`

Then try again.
If you are an avid user of LaTeX, you might consider using TeXLive or MiKTeX with your [favorite text editor](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides), which will do this conversion for you.

Here is the converted eps to png:

[image: converted file]

If you have more issues, let me know and we can iron them out.

Comment: For whatever reason, the journal is adamant that the author **must** upload as .eps. I'll try it anyway and see if it goes through.

Comment: Yes - the .png image will not convert at all, so I wonder if it's something else. I'll tweet you to avoid making LaTeXers unhappy.